# Sort MySQL query by a single match, then normally

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I'm mildly familiar with MySQL queries, but I've got one tricky thing that I can't figure out how to do.  Is there a way to tell the system "anything matching X-condition first, otherwise order normally."  For example, in a table `posts` with the fields `(post_id, author_id, timestamp)` I know how to do...

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY timestamp");
```

But is there a way to have a certain user's posts (say, `author_id = 5`) show up at the top of the results, and then sort by timestamp after that?  To be clear: I DON'T want to sort by `author_id`, I just want to isolate the posts where `author_id` is 5 specifically, and then sort by `timestamp` for everything else.

Is there a way to do that?  I've tried,

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY author_id = 5, timestamp");
```

...but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY FIELD(author_id, '5') DESC, timestamp
```

Comment: It seems to be working, except it's placing the matched rows (the `author_id = 5` rows) at the bottom of the results rather than the top.  A single `DESC` after the `FIELD()` worked beautifully.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN author_id=5 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END , timestamp
```

This works for most of *RDBMS* , for *MySQL* specfic use *@notulysses*'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think Reza's query would look something like:

```
SELECT  * FROM posts WHERE author_id = 5
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM posts WHERE author_id <> 5 ORDER BY timestamp)
```

This will place `author_id` 5's results at the top, then the rest are by timestamp.